# Is it possible to seperate tab and indentation configuration in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure Visual Studio Code to treat tab characters in files as being 8 spaces but have indentation (when I hit tab on the keyboard) as being 4 spaces. Is this at all possible?

I can achieve this in eclipse with the code style formatter but can't achieve the same thing in VS Code.

(I've submitted an issue to the VS Code repository on git hub now https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42643)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your user settings (or workspace settings) in VS Code. By default, it is set a tab as 4 spaces.

You can modify the setting `"editor.tabSize": 4,` and set that to 8.

However, also be aware that `"editor.detectIndentation": true,` is set to try by default and this causes VS Code to detect the indication size of the file you open. So if the file itself has spacing set to say 4 or even 2, then VS Code will auto set spaces to that value while that file is open...or until you convert indentation.

You can convert indentation via the command palette and that should update the spacing to your desired setting.

Comment: I've tried turning "detect indentation" off and changing the tab size but it's not really what I'm after, I also don't want to reformat a whole file just to change a few lines in it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen, No.

It appears that VS code still can't separate the two concepts of tab size and indentation distance. Some suggestions, ideas and hopeful soulmates of ours can be found in this issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5394#issuecomment-215414643

I agree with the comments in that issue in that separating the tab size from the indentation distance is a nice feature that solves several problems. The only thing needed is for someone to actually do the work to implement that in vs code.

Or, a less intrusive route, I have actually been thinking about creating an extension to override the indentation action in some way and use a custom settings variable for the indentation distance there... but I have yet to learn enough about the internals of VS code to determine if that's even possible for an extension to do.